# RAC 4.0 How to chain SignalProducers correctly?

Tags: ios, swift, reactive-cocoa, reactive-cocoa-3

I have a view model with a few different functions that look like:

```
func somethingSignal() -> SignalProducer<Void, NSError>
{
    return SignalProducer {
        sink, disposable in

        sink.sendNext(blabla)
        sink.sendCompleted()
    }
}
```

Now, these signals need to be run in sequence - one cannot start before the preivous has been Completed. I therefore have another function called something like:

```
func setup() -> SignalProducer<Void, NSError>
{
    return somethingSignal()
         .then(somethingSignal2())
         .then(somethingSignal3())
}
```

I was under the impression that `then` is the function to use for this sort of behaviour. Signal3 shouldn't begin until Signal2 has completed, which shouldn't start until Signal1 has completed.

The function that calls `setup` has the `start()` call.

Where am I going wrong with this?

Comment: What error are you seeing from this?

Comment: I was being a muppet and had a check on a property expecting non-nil outside of the SignalProducer block. Of course, the function returns the SignalProducer before actually performing the block. False alarm, all fixed!

Answer (score 1):

That looks correct!

Alternatively, you can concatenate all the signals:

```
SignalProducer<SignalProducer<(), NSError>, NSError>(values: [
    somethingSignal(),
    somethingSignal2(),
    somethingSignal3()
])
    .flatten(.Concat)
```

Since your type is `Void` you probably don't care about the values emitted. If you do, however, note that this has slightly different semantics: it will emit values from all the signals, unlike `then`.